# Проблема с async

Tags: c#, async-await

Проблема с методом async. Не знаю как решить ее

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ChemistryMath
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {


        }
    }
    class Chemistry
    {
        //Main method
        public static async void Table(string symbol, int i)
        {
            string[] str_arr = File.ReadAllLines("table.txt");
            Tasks(symbol, str_arr);

        }

        //Create tasks
        private static void Tasks(string symbol, string[] str_arr)
        {
            Task task = new Task(Search(str_arr, symbol, 0, 30));
        }

        //Search symbol
        static string Search(string[] file, string symbol, int from = 0, int to = 120)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(@symbol);
            MatchCollection matches;
            for (;from <= to; from++)
            {
                matches = reg.Matches(file[from]);
               if(matches.Count > 1)
                {
                    return file[from];
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первый шаг для решения проблемы — опубликовать код в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/BurlywoodProperEsok

Answer (score 5):

Мой хрустальный шар говорит, что вы спутали вызов функции с самой функцией. В вашем коде аргументом конструктора `Task` является результат работы функции `Search`, то есть значение типа `string`. А вы наверняка хотели упаковать в `Action` вызов функции.

Для этого просто создайте лямбду, вызывающую вашу функцию, и скармливайте её в конструктор `Task`'а.